# Problems on boot Ubuntu 13.04, kernel version 3.8.0 with UEFI

Tags: boot, 13.04, uefi

few days ago I UPGRADED my Ubuntu 12.10 to Ubuntu 13.04 version on my NP300E5C samsung notebook with ssd.
I reloaded ubuntu few times and everything has gone well, BUT after a complete shutdown I restarted my notebook and, loading Kernel version 3.8.0, it hangs on black screen and Ubuntu cannot load. It works only selecting kernel version 3.5.0; I don't have a dual boot.
I boot Ubuntu with UEFI boot-loader embedded in my samsung pc.
Please help me, it is my working pc and is very important to have all things working fine for my job.
Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear from your description what boot manager and boot loader you're using. If you're using GRUB, then Frank's suggestion might work, at least in the short term. (There might be problems if/when further kernel upgrades come along, should the working 3.5.0 kernel be deleted.)

It sounds like you may be using the [EFI stub loader,](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/efistub.html) though. If so, you should be aware that some users have begun having problems with it in the 3.7.x and 3.8.x series. The cause isn't yet clear. [This thread](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=156670) on the Arch Linux forum discusses the issue in detail. If you're running into this problem, then either a reconfiguration of your boot manager to boot 3.5.0 by default or switching from the EFI stub loader to another boot loader (such as GRUB 2 or ELILO) is in order. Reconfiguring your boot manager requires knowing which one you're using, and perhaps *how* you're using it.

Answer (score 0):

In your /boot directory you will find two kernel images - two files named initrd.img-3....

Keep them.

Using the Ubuntu Software Center install the Grub Customizer Program

In the List Configuration tab of that program you can drag & drop the 3.5-image before the 3.8-image.

So your system will automatically boot the 3.5-kernel.

Comment: can plz suggest a grub customizer program. the current one in the software centre is a legacy version.